# What are the Esperanto terms for "Wales" and "Welsh"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What are the Esperanto terms for ["Wales"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wales) (one of the countries in the United Kingdom) and "Welsh"?

Answer (score 3):

[According to Wikipedia](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimrio) and Google Translate it's "Kimrio" for the country and accordingly "kimro" for a member of the people and "la kimra" for the language.

The [PIV entry](http://vortaro.net/#kimro) seems to confirm this, but is kinda hard to find if you don't already know one of these words.

Comment: That's why dictionaries like [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/) (Reta Vortaro) are so useful.

Comment: Indeed, and have a look at [ESPDIC](http://denisowski.org/Esperanto/Esperanto.html) as well—but use that one with care, because it does have some mistakes or weird/awkward/unusual words that aren't really used. I like to use it for inspiration, to try to work out what terms to look for in other dictionaries, and for that purpose, it's really helpful. (ReVo I find very often does not have the words I look for.)

Comment: I did try to search for "Welsh" in simplavortaro.org, which is AFAIK based on the ReVo data, but [that search](http://www.simplavortaro.org/serĉo?s=Welsh) didn't come up with anything.

Comment: I tend to use mostly Wikipedia as many modern expressions are not in any dictionary.

Comment: I don't fully trust Wikipedia as translation / Esperanto terms source, as it sometimes uses too-literally-translated-from-English terms that don't really capture the essence/meaning as an Esperanto word usually should, depending on who wrote an article and when. Then again, that doesn't seem to be the case with "kimro", which obviously isn't based on the English language term for "Welsh person".